# Update all i18n fields from an action

Tags: internationalization, symfony1, symfony-1.4

What I'm trying to do is relatively simple but I can't find documentation.

Let's say I have a model `Thing` with a field `label`. The `label` field is internationalized.

How can I update all `label` fields from a model or an action?

(I'm using Doctrine)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't say which ORM you're using so I assumed Doctrine.

You can update/set internationalized fields in the following way:

```
$thing = new Thing();
$thing->Translation['en']->label = 'My Label';
$thing->Translation['nl']->label = 'Mijn Label';
$thing->save();
```

Of course if your object is already persisted you have to retrieve it first.

Read more in symfony and doctrine docs:

- http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/19#chapter_19_sub_doctrine_objects
- http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/behaviors/en#core-behaviors:i18n

Comment: Yes, sorry I'm using Doctrine.
This seems to work, thank you :)